# how can I update SQLite table with new column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In sqlite, my table is as follows:

```
---------------------
Date           Temp
---------------------
201309010051    82
201309010151    81
201309010251    80
---------------------
```

I generate a query as follows which modifies the datetime format from 201309010051 to 2013-09-01 00:51.

Here is the query which I use to do this for all values in the 'Date' column:

```
select substr(Date, 1, 4)||"-"||substr(Date, 5, 2)||"-"||substr(Date, 7, 2) 
||" "||substr(Date, 9, 2)||":"||substr(Date, 11, 2) as CreatedColumn  
from myTable
```

Now, I want to add the 'CreatedColumn' to my original table. I tried the following:

```
update myTable set CreatedColumn = <my above query which modifies the datetime format>
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "select": syntax error
```

How can I add/append the 'CreatedColumn' produced from my query to the original table?

Comment: Please include the exact UPDATE query you tried.

Comment: Have you considered storing your date/time as epoch time? And leave any formatting that needs to be done to your presentation layer.

Comment: @joseph No, the _whole_ query.

Comment: @duskwuff `update myTable set CreatedColumn = select substr(Date, 1, 4)||"-"||substr(Date, 5, 2)||"-"||substr(Date, 7, 2) ||" "||substr(Date, 9, 2)||":"||substr(Date, 11, 2)` . The error was inclusion of `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the column `CreatedColumn` you can set the value of the column for each row with the following query:

```
UPDATE
    myTable 
SET 
    CreatedColumn = substr(Date, 1, 4)||"-"||substr(Date, 5, 2)||"-"||substr(Date, 7, 2) ||" "||substr(Date, 9, 2)||":"||substr(Date, 11, 2)
```

Comment: This is not what you did in your example. In your example you have `SET SELECT...`, which is not what you can see in my example. Read carefully my code :)

Comment: Great :) happy to help

Answer (score 3):

The query that @Dekel wrote is correct for inserting the data. Before add information to the new column, you must first need to create it.

-- Initial Creation of the table and insert of data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable`; 
CREATE TABLE `myTable`(
    `Date` int, 
    `Temp` int
); 

INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES (201309010051,82),
                             (201309010151,81),
                             (201309010251,80);
```

-- SELECT *:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable`;
+------------+------+
| Date       | Temp |
+------------+------+
| 2147483647 |   82 |
| 2147483647 |   81 |
| 2147483647 |   80 |
+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- Alter table

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD COLUMN `CreatedColumn` DATETIME; 

SELECT * FROM `myTable`;
    +------------+------+---------------+
    | Date       | Temp | CreatedColumn |
    +------------+------+---------------+
    | 2147483647 |   82 | NULL          |
    | 2147483647 |   81 | NULL          |
    | 2147483647 |   80 | NULL          |
    +------------+------+---------------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- Update CreatedColumn - Using Dekel's command

```
UPDATE
    `myTable` 
SET 
    `CreatedColumn` = substr(Date, 1, 4)||"-"||substr(Date, 5, 2)||"-"||substr(Date, 7, 2) ||" "||substr(Date, 9, 2)||":"||substr(Date, 11, 2);
```

-- Show changes to table

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable`; 
    +------------+------+---------------------+
    | Date       | Temp | CreatedColumn       |
    +------------+------+---------------------+
    | 2147483647 |   82 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
    | 2147483647 |   81 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
    | 2147483647 |   80 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
    +------------+------+---------------------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```